# how to set android HorizontalScrollView right-to-left behavior (default selected tab from the right side, not the left)

Tags: android, android-tabs

how do I set the HorizontalScrollView to behave in a right-to-left manner?
The default behavior is that the first tab (the default tab) that is shown is from the left side .
i want the tabs to be sorted in reverse,so that the first 'default' tab will be on the right side of the screen.

how do i do that? 
I used layout_gravity but it didn't work ..

Here is my layout code , containing the tabhost and the HorizontalScrollView :

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: `HorizontalScrollView` does not have tabs.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround that works:

```
final HorizontalScrollView view = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        }, 10);
```

The idea is that programmatic scrolling needs a delay for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this is too late, but for anyone else out there with a similar question:

```
horizontalScrollView.post {
        horizontalScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)
    }
```

you should not use delayed version of post. because post will be added to the end of the message queue.